# Buftype=nofile when switching buffers with :Vexplore

Tags: buffers, split, netrw

When I open up `:Vexplore` in a split and open a file in it, the file in the other split ends up with `buftype=nofile` set so I can't write in that file or anything.
But the new buffer that was opened with `:Explore` has `buftype=.` This is annoying as all hell and I want to fix it. Anybody know how?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem; which version of Vim are you using? And which commands are you using? If I use `vim` (no file), and the `:Vexplore`, then both windows have `buftype=` (empty).

Comment: I think I just found that the issue was having set autochdir in my vimrc.

Comment: When this happens to me in ViM... `:set buftype=`

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug but has been fixed as of version 162g, which you can find [here](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/#NETRW).