# Strange behavior between autochdir and netrw

Tags: buffers, netrw

This has been plaguing me for a while now, but I've only just recently been able to come up with an MCVE.

The problem is that when `autochdir` is on and I use `:Explore` to open netrw sometimes it will set the `buftype` of the original buffer to `nofile`. This is very annoying as if I come back to the buffer later and try to save it, I get the error `E382: Cannot write, 'buftype' option is set`. I then have to `set buftype=` to save. I know I'm not the only one who has [seen this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3671/buftype-nofile-when-switching-buffers-with-vexplore).

MCVE: `set autochdir`. Open an already existing file and make an edit (don't save). Use `:Explore` to open netrw. Close the netrw window. Use `:Explore` to open netrw again. Return to the original file and note: `set buftype?`. It should be set to `nofile`.

I'm using vim 8.0.69 on Win7. It happens on both vim and Gvim. Can anyone else reproduce this, and do you have any suggestions on how to get it to stop? (Other than unsetting `autochdir`)

Comment: you should report this to Charles (or better yet, check if the latest upstream [netrw package](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/#NETRW) also has this problem and then report to Charles)

Comment: Sure, I'll look into that. I was just going to try here first in case it's not a bug and just something I'm not understanding/not doing right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I contacted Dr. Chip and he confirmed that it was indeed a bug. He has since fixed the bug. The most recent version (162g as of this writing) is available on his [website](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/#NETRW).